# Hive SQL Removing Empty Elements In The Array

Tags: sql, arrays, hive, hiveql

I'm not sure how to remove empty elements within Hive arrays.  To give context, 
I have a table name `tbl1` with six columns `(key_1, v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4, v_5)`.  When I query below:

```
SELECT 
        key1,
        array( nvl(v_1,""),
                nvl(v_2,""),
                nvl(v_3,""),
                nvl(v_4,""),
                nvl(v_4,""),
                nvl(v_5,"")) v_array

FROM
    tbl1;
```

This result produces:

```
key1, v_array
1, ["a","b","c","d",""]
2, ["a","b","c","",""]
3, ["a","b","","",""]
```

However I want my result to look like below:

```
key1, v_array
1, ["a","b","c","d"]
2, ["a","b","c"]
3, ["a","b"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a custom UDF, but it might be easier to do a LATERAL VIEW explode, followed by a collect

```
SELECT key1, 
      collect( val ) as v_array
FROM 
 ( SELECT key1,
          v.val as val 
   LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE( array( v1, v2, v3, v4, v5 ) ) v as val
     FROM tbl1
   WHERE val is not null
 ) lve ;
```

Comment: thanks, it works but I have to move the FROM clause before the start of LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE.  One question is there any way to sort the array elements?  I queried it against my "real table" and its not in order as expected, for example v1 values ends up at the last row.

Comment: If you add a "DISTRIBUTE BY SORT BY" to the inner SELECT, it should be ordered according to those keys. ( ie DISTRIBUTE BY key1 SORT BY key1, val ).  You might need to use a timestamp or other field to order the right way though.